# How to fix "Connection timed out" error when trying to make python app (Flask + Nginx) be accessible via public IP?

Tags: apache, nginx, flask, uwsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to host a python app on my AWS EC2 instance, so it can be accessible via public IP for everyone. I did [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04) step by step but I faced a problem when was trying to [create WSGI application](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-ubuntu-14-04#create-a-wsgi-application).
When I try to run my app and to access website `curl my_public_ip:5111` it gives me error: `curl: (28) Failed to connect to my_public_ip port 5111 after 131072 ms: Connection timed out`
Same thing happened when I tried to run my Flask app with Apache - app works perfectly on localhost and with private IP, but not with public IP (same error).

When I do `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`, I see all the ports appear in LISTEN, but the website won't load.

I set my_port to be allowed by firewall `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5111 -j ACCEPT` but it didn't solve the problem.

Static page opens correctly with Apache (and with Nginx or other server), but python app doesn't open.

My simple Flask app.py example:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

import gevent.pywsgi

app_server = gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0",5111), app)
app_server.serve_forever()
```

Then I do `python app.py` and it works with localhost & private ip only.

I also tried to run my simple wsgi.py:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ["<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"]
```

I do `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5111 -w wsgi` and receive this:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.21 (64bit) on [Mon Apr 10 23:08:16 2023] ***
compiled with version: 11.3.0 on 08 April 2023 10:16:31
os: Linux-5.19.0-1022-aws #23~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 17 15:38:24 UTC 2023
nodename: ip-172-31-5-32
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /home/asya/myapp
detected binary path: /home/asya/flask-app/flask_env/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 31727
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:5111 fd 3
Python version: 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55ea0a172d80
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72904 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x55ea0a172d80 pid: 372149 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 372149, cores: 1)
```

And website does't load.

What am I missing and how to make my app available via public IP?

Comment: Is `0.0.0.0:5111-protocol=http` a typo in the post? `--socket 0.0.0.0:5111` should be sufficient.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith yes thanks, I've edited my post now. although it didn't change the situation

Comment: I know that on Azure, you have to configure security to allow traffic from public to reach your system.  It is not enough to have the ports listen and iptables.  I assume something similar exists in AWS.

Comment: @Nic3500 yes that's exactly what I've done with `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5111 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: No I mean in the AWS configuration directly. Ex in Azure you have to configure networking to link the external connections to the VM.